# combing rowspan with colspan in html table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, col

I want to combine all 3 5's like left side 1, combine all 1's like left side 3, and combine all 6's like top-left 4. Any one can help me solve this? i know I should use col span and row span but in my solution 2 rows will gone so I have no clues how to solve it now.

```html
<div class="table-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <table class="col-md-8 table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" rowspan="5">4</td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">1</td>
          <td colspan="2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">3</td>
          <td colspan="2">1</td>
          <td colspan="4">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">1</td>
          <td colspan="4">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">1</td>
          <td colspan="4">6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7zt7vwmd/5/

```
<div class="table-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <table class="col-md-8 table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" rowspan="5">4</td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">1</td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" rowspan="5">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">3</td>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is the effect you are trying to describe. Unless you are married to tables, you may want to look into CSS grid to display your data.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I want, thank you so much!